# Combining daily Welford computed variance into monthly

Tags: algorithm, statistics, variance, standard-deviation

I'm successfully using Welford's method to compute running variance and standard deviation as described many times on Stack Overflow and [John D Cook's excellent blog post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/).

I store the timestamp, count, sum, and running calculation of "Sk" and stdev in a database table PER DAY.

I would like to combine or rollup the daily computed count,sum, and Sk values get a MONTHLY standard deviation.

John D Cook's blog has [another post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/skewness_kurtosis/) that provides an algorithm to combine two "RunningStats" into 1 (see operator+ method).  This works for combining 2 days into 1.  I could use this to iterate through the days to combine all days in the month.  However, unlike calculating daily stdev where I have a large number of samples that must be dealt with in a streaming fashion, I have access to all the daily data, and would like a single formula to combine all days in the month at once.  That would lend itself to creation of a database view.

It does not appear that simply summing up the Sk values and dividing by the total monthly count - 1 produces accurate variance.

Example Data:

```
DATE, COUNT, SUM, Sk, STDDEV
1-Jun-15, 60, 514, 1556.733336, 5.14
2-Jun-15, 51, 455, 1523.686274, 5.52
3-Jun-15, 61, 556, 1494.196722, 4.99
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `x1, ..., xn` be the values for one day. Then, as I understand it, `Sk` is defined (mathematically; the rolling implementation is different) as follows.

```
Mk = (sum_{i=1}^n xi) / n     [Mk = SUM / COUNT]
Sk = sum_{i=1}^n (xi - Mk)^2.
```

The problem with summing the `Sk` column is that each value is computed with respect to a different mean, so the overall variance is an underestimate. Instead, we should have a term like

```
sum_{i=1}^n (xi - (Mk + delta))^2,
```

which we rewrite in terms of the existing quantities.

```
  sum_{i=1}^n (xi - (Mk + delta))^2
= sum_{i=1}^n (xi - Mk - delta)^2
= sum_{i=1}^n ((xi - Mk)^2 - 2 (xi - Mk) delta + delta^2)
= Sk + n delta^2.
```

Here `delta` is the monthly mean minus the daily mean. Once again, I do not warrant numerical stability.